# Django ModelFormset use specific ModelForm instead of auto-generated one

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I use a specific ModelForm as the form for my modelformset_factory?

I'm using django-form-utilities to have a BetterModelForm, and I would like to use that same form as the basis of my formset.  I have thought that I could write my own custom factory that extends formset, but I was guessing there is an easier way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to extend native `modelformset_factory()`. Look at the definition of this function in the django's source code:

```
def modelformset_factory(model, form=ModelForm, formfield_callback=None,
    formset=BaseModelFormSet,
    extra=1, can_delete=False, can_order=False,
    max_num=None, fields=None, exclude=None)
```

You can just pass your custom modelform via `form` parameter, but not the actual instance - you need to pass the form ref itself, so use ie. MyModelForm insted of  MyModelForm().